# My Query Run Slow Mysql

Tags: mysql

SELECT (inv_total - isc_total) AS profit FROM(
SELECT
SUM(inv.net_weight * inv.unit_price)  AS isc_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN (i.".$ex_gst."ex_gst = 'YES')
THEN (inv.net_weight * (CASE WHEN (i.final = 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NOT NULL) THEN (ind.final_unit_price * cr.currency_value)
                                    WHEN (i.final = 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NULL) THEN ind.final_unit_price
                                    WHEN (i.final <> 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NOT NULL) THEN (ind.unit_price * cr.currency_value)
                                    WHEN (i.final <> 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NULL) THEN ind.unit_price ELSE ind.unit_price END ) * 1.06)
                            ELSE (inv.net_weight * ( CASE WHEN (i.final = 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NOT NULL) THEN (ind.final_unit_price * cr.currency_value)
                                    WHEN (i.final = 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NULL) THEN ind.final_unit_price
                                    WHEN (i.final <> 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NOT NULL) THEN (ind.unit_price * cr.currency_value)
                                    WHEN (i.final <> 'Y' AND i.currency_id IS NULL) THEN ind.unit_price
                                    ELSE ind.unit_price END )
                            ) END
                        )AS inv_total
FROM ".$prefix_qry."inventory inv
                        INNER JOIN ".$prefix_qry."osc_detail osc_do ON osc_do.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id
                        INNER JOIN product p ON inv.product_id = p.product_id
                        LEFT JOIN ".$prefix_qry."isc isc ON inv.isc_batch_no = isc.isc_batch_no
                        INNER JOIN supplier s ON isc.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
                        INNER JOIN ".$prefix_qry."invoice i ON inv.osc_id = i.osc_id
                        INNER JOIN ".$prefix_qry."invoice_detail ind ON i.invoice_id = ind.invoice_id AND ind.product_id = p.product_id
                        LEFT JOIN currency cr ON i.currency_id = cr.currency_id
                        WHERE inv.osc_id !=''
                        AND inv.inventory_type = 'CONFIRM'
                        AND i.cancel_by IS NULL
                        AND s.supplier_id = '".$supp_id."'
                        AND MONTH(i.date_of_delivery) = '".$month."'
AND YEAR(i.date_of_delivery) = '".$year ."') AS A

Comment: Thank you for sharing a status report. Your query runs slow. Was there a *question* ?

Answer (score 0):

To allow MySQL to make effective use of a range scan on an index with date_of_delivery as a leading column, assuming $year represents a valid year, and $month is a value between 1 and 12, then change this:

```
     AND MONTH(i.date_of_delivery) = '".$month."'
     AND YEAR(i.date_of_delivery) = '".$year ."'
```

To something like this:

```
     AND i.date_of_delivery >= STR_TO_DATE('".$year."-".$month."-01','%Y-%m-%d')
     AND i.date_of_delivery  < STR_TO_DATE('".$year."-".$month."-01','%Y-%m-%d') 
                               + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

The "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN` to `isc` is negated by the subsequent inner join to `s`. That is, an equivalent result would be obtained replacing the `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

Make sure suitable indexes are available, and are being used.

The EXPLAIN output will show the execution plan.

Other than that, we'd really need to see the EXPLAIN output. That will give us a clue as to what indexes are available, table statistics, and so on. For really digging in, we would need to know the definitions of all indexes for all tables involved in the query, and the datatypes of the columns involved in the  predicates.

---

Given that the inline view query returns a single row, the overhead of the derived table is negligible.

This query should return a result equivalent to the original inline view.

```
SELECT SUM( inv.net_weight
          * inv.unit_price
       ) AS isc_total
     , SUM( inv.net_weight
          * IF(( i.".$ex_gst."ex_gst = 'YES' ), 1.06, 1.00)
          * IF(( i.final = 'Y' ), ind.final_unit_price, ind.unit_price)
          * IF(( i.final IS NULL OR i.currency_id IS NULL ), 1.00, cr.currency_value)
       ) AS inv_total
  FROM ".$prefix_qry."invoice i
  JOIN ".$prefix_qry."invoice_detail ind
    ON ind.invoice_id       = i.invoice_id
  JOIN ".$prefix_qry."inventory inv
    ON inv.product_id       = ind.product_id
   AND inv.inventory_type   = 'CONFIRM'
   AND inv.osc_id           = i.osc_id
   AND inv.osc_id          != ''
  JOIN ".$prefix_qry."osc_detail osc_do
    ON osc_do.inventory_id  = inv.inventory_id
  JOIN ".$prefix_qry."isc isc
    ON isc.supplier_id      = '".$supp_id."'
   AND isc.isc_batch_no     = inv.isc_batch_no
  JOIN supplier s
    ON s.supplier_id        = '".$supp_id."'
   AND s.supplier_id        = isc.supplier_id
  JOIN product p
    ON p.product_id         = inv.product_id
   AND p.product_id         = ind.product_id
  LEFT
  JOIN currency cr
    ON cr.currency_id       = i.currency_id
 WHERE i.cancel_by         IS NULL
   AND i.osc_id            != ''
   AND i.date_of_delivery  >= DATE_FROM_STR('".$year."-".$month."-01','%Y-%m-%d')
   AND i.date_of_delivery   < DATE_FROM_STR('".$year."-".$month."-01','%Y-%m-%d')
                              + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Summary of column usage in SELECT list

```
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
i        final, currency_id, $[ex_gst]ex_gst
inv      net_weight,unit_price
cr       currency_value
```

Summary of column usage in PREDICATES

```
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
i        osc_id, invoice_id, cancel_by, date_of_delivery
ind      invoice_id
inv      inventory_id, isc_batch_no, osc_id, inventory_type, product_id
isc      isc_batch_no, supplier_id
osc_do   inventory_id
p        product_id
s        supplier_id
cr       currency_id
```

Likely these tables are smaller and already have these columns as PRIMARY KEY

```
... ON p       (product_id)
... ON s       (supplier_id)
... ON cr      (currency_id)
```

We should consider whether it's *necessary* to include the `product` (`p`) and `supplier` (`s`) tables in the query. If the columns used (shown above) for `p` and `s` are PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY, and if these foreign key constraints are enforced:

```
 inv (product_id)  references p (product_id)
 ind (product_id)  references p (product_id)
 isc (supplier_id) references s (supplier_id)
```

then the joins to `p` and `s` won't affect the result. That is, those tables could be removed from the query.

A first cut at covering indexes that might help the optimizer generate an efficient execution plan...

```
... ON i       (date_of_delivery,cancel_by,osc_id,invoice_id,final,currency_id,[$ex_gst]ex_gst)
... ON ind     (invoice_id, product_id)
... ON inv     (inventory_id,inventory_type,isc_batch_no,osc_id,inventory_type,product_id,net_weight,unit_price)
... ON isc     (supplier_id,isc_batch_no)
... ON osc_do  (inventory_id)
```